# Finding an optimal positive $x$ that minimizes two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

I have two equations seen below:

$$
d=1.5 \cdot 10^8x
$$
$$
v=\frac{1.885}{x}
$$

Both of these equations are in terms of $x$, where $x>0$.

Using the two equations above, I want to find the $x$ value where both $d$ and $v$ are at their smallest possible values, in order to have an optimal value of $x$.

Before going on to solve a three variable optimisation problem, the first thing that has to happen is to combine the two equations into one equation in terms of three variables: $x,d$ and $v$. How can I combine the two equations to form one?

I imagine the result to be a function in the form of: $(x,,)=.........$

I could then go on and optimise that function in terms of three variables.

Comment: As $x$ increases, $d$ increases while $v$ decreases - so minimising both simultaneously does not make much sense, in fact minimum of $d$ here is when $v$ is maximum and vice versa. There is really one independent variable, and it is unclear exactly what you want to minimise with that.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, it should be better clarified how we have to interpret the search for the smallest possible values of $d$ and $v$. For increasing values of $x$, $d$ increases and $v$ decreases, and vice versa. In particular, the $dv$ product is constant, since by a simple substitution we have

$$dv=2.8275 \cdot 10^8$$

A possible way to interpret this problem is to search a sort of balance by finding the $x$ value that equalizes $d$ and $v$. This value leads to $d=v=\sqrt{2.8275} \cdot 10^4\approx 16815.2$ and is given by

$$x=\frac{1.885}{\sqrt{2.8275} \cdot 10^4}\approx 0.000121$$

Clearly this is only one of the possible interpretations, and other solutions may be possible if we search other types of optimization.

Comment: I imagine the result to be a function in the form of: $f(x,d,v)=........$. I could then go on and optimise that function in terms of three variables. Is that possible?

Comment: You cannot get a function in that form simply starting from the two equations that you provided. As already stated in the comments, actually we have a single independent variable. You have to better clarify what you want to minimize.